# How to use "happen to" like this?

Tags: meaning, usage

This is a script from the movie "Midnight in Paris":

> "It's fine for your father and I to disagree. That's what a democracy is. Your father defends the right-wing of the Republican Party, and I **happen to** think you almost got to be - like a demented lunatic, but it's like... "

I understand "happen to" means like *unintentionally*, *by chance*.

This is a comedy film and I'm assuming that works in a sarcastic or ironical way there, but then I don't understand the core image.

Comment: There is a better source for this script at http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Midnight-in-Paris.html. The one you've quoted has grammar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster at http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/happen

> HAPPEN verb [no object]
>
> 1 
>   : to take place especially without being planned : occur
>   Mistakes/Accidents will happen.
>   Something like that was bound to happen sooner or later.
>   You never know what's going to happen when they get together.
>   [+] more examples
>
> 2 
>   not used in progressive tenses
>
> a  : to do or be something by chance — followed by to + verb
>   The children happened to be asleep when we called.
>   I happened to overhear their conversation.
>   I happen to know his brother.
>   Do you happen to know the way to the station?
>
> b  — used with it to describe something that occurs by chance
>   It (so) happened that the children were asleep when we called.
>   It happened to rain that day.
>   As it happened, it rained that day.
>   It (just so) happens that I know his brother.
>
> c  — used to make an angry or forceful statement — followed by to + verb
>   The woman you've been looking at happens to be my wife!
>   I **happen to think** that the movie was actually very good.

"Your father defends the right-wing of the Republican party, and I happen to think you almost got to be - like a demented lunatic," is meant as hyperbole by the character who is speaking.

Comment: If you must downvote, please leave a *constructive* comment or *improve my answer* by editing it (I actually *welcome* assistance in providing better answers).